# Identifying Overlapping time periods in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following sample data

```
begin_date              end_date
-------------------------------------------
2014-08-27 07:10:00     2014-08-27 07:30:00
2014-08-27 07:30:00     2014-08-27 07:50:00
2014-08-27 07:40:00     2014-08-27 08:00:00
2014-08-27 07:50:00     2014-08-27 08:10:00
2014-08-27 08:10:00     2014-08-27 08:30:00
2014-08-27 08:30:00     2014-08-27 08:50:00
2014-08-27 08:30:00     2014-08-27 08:50:00
```

I want to identify overlapping time periods.

The expected output is

```
2014-08-27 07:30:00     2014-08-27 07:50:00
2014-08-27 07:40:00     2014-08-27 08:00:00
2014-08-27 07:50:00     2014-08-27 08:10:00
2014-08-27 08:30:00     2014-08-27 08:50:00
2014-08-27 08:30:00     2014-08-27 08:50:00
```

(2014-08-27 08:30:00    2014-08-27 08:50:00 overlap with another pair of same data itself)

Please help me out..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two time periods A and B overlap iff `(begin(A) < end(B)) && (end(A) >= begin(B))`. Does that help?

Maybe try something like this:

```
select p1.begin_date, p1.end_date, ' overlaps ', p2.begin_date, p2.end_date
from periodTable p1
inner join periodTable p2
    on p1.begin_date < p2.end_date
    and p1.end_date >= p2.begin_date
```

Edit:

In response to Tanner's comment, I suggest an elaborated version of the above:

```
select p1.begin_date, p1.end_date
from periodTable p1
inner join periodTable p2
    on p1.begin_date < p2.end_date
    and p1.end_date > p2.begin_date
group by p1.begin_date, p1.end_date
having count(*) > 1
```

This will yield all overlapping *periods*, but *not* the individual *records* from the table, that is, each period will only be returned once. (This corresponds to the puristic relational algebra view and is a result of the lack of a primary key.)

Comment: Sure, if you run it against the source data it returns 18 rows rather than the expected output: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b10441/1. I'm guessing you didn't test it?

Comment: Ok, I got your point. Thanks for checking. Yes, I just threw the SQL in without testing it. However, it works just as expected. - Of course, you get *all* combinations of overlapping periods as a result, but it's an illustration that's really easy to adapt to a desired output format. The two main points are a) that you have to join the table to itself, and b) how to compare the intervals. "a" is the answer to about half the SQL questions on SO, and "b" is specific to this question. Both concepts combined solve the OP's problem, while the final choice of projection is trivial.

Comment: Thaks, this saved a lot of time for me today!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT  REsult.DtFrom, REsult.DtTo
FROM
(
SELECT DtFrom, DtTo, CASE WHEN DtFrom <= cast((LAG(DtTo) OVER(ORDER BY DtFrom, DtTo)) as datetime)
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsOverlapping
 FROM 
dbo.Dates_Overlap
) AS REsult
WHERE IsOverlapping = 1 
ORDER BY DtFrom, DtTo;
```